# WASAPI shared mode: What amplitude does the audio engine expect?

Tags: c++, audio, wasapi

*I previously messed up with this question. I made it sound as though I'm asking about my particular implementation, but my question is actually about the general topic. I am pretty confident, that my implementation is OK. So I am rewriting this question:*

WASAPI gives me information about the audio format that the audio engine accepts in shared mode. I know the expected bit depth of the samples I provide to the buffer. **What I don't know, is the expected representation of the signal amplitude in the samples.** For example, if the audio engine expects 32 bit samples, does it mean, that I should represent a sine wave amplitude as:

- `long` in range `[min, max]`
- `unsigned long` in range `[0, max]`
- `float` in range `[min, max]`
- or even something like `float` in range `[-1, 1]`?

(`max = std::numeric_limits<type>::max()` and `min = ...::min()` in `C++`)

So far I've been experimenting with this with different values by trial and error method. It seems, that only when my samples contain numbers `max/2` or `-min/2` (as a `long`) alternating (along with other numbers), it produces a sound. Even numbers close to these (+- a few integers) produce the same results. When these two numbers (or numbers close to them) are not present in the samples, the result is silence no matter what I do.

It may be irrelevant, but I noticed, that these numbers' (`max/2` and `min/2`) bit representation (as `long`s) is identical to `IEEE float` bit representation of `2.0` and `-2.0`. It still makes no sense to me, why it works like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper look into the `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` structure I found out, that the information I needed might be stored in the `SubFormat` property. In my case, it was `KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT`. So the audio engine was expecting 32 bit `float`s in a range of `[-1, +1]`. For some reason my previous test with float values was unsuccessful, so I kept on trying with integers. Now a simple sine function in the `[-1, +1]` range provides a correct result. There are some glitches in the sound, but this may be related to some timing issues, when waiting for the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The typical representation is float -1 to 1 scaled to a fixed point representation. For 32-bit signed you'd ideally like 1 to map to 0x7fffffff and -1 to map to 0x8000000. However, you need to keep in mind that there is asymmetry around 0 such that there is one more negative value than there are positive values. In other words, you shouldn't use 0x80000000 otherwise you'll risk overflow on the positive side.

```
int xfixed = (int)(xfloat * 0x7fffffff);
```

More explicitly:

```
int xfixed = (int)(xfloat * ((1<<(32-1)) - 1));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for the explanation of the overflow problem. I didn't realize that. It didn't help though. I solved the problem and will post it as an answer.